# Advantage/disadvantage of using SecureStorage and Preferences, over "regular" method calls?

Tags: c#, maui

In .Net MAUI, the developer has the option of using [Secure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android) and [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android), to store key/value pairs.

I'm currently in a situation where I call an API, to retrieve a simple value. Either a string or an integer. This value needs to be read on subsequent pages in my app.

**Are there any advantages of using the previously mentioned storage methods, or should I just call the API again, on other pages?**

Comment: Yes, making repeated network calls to retrieve the same value is not a good use of resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any advantages of using the previously mentioned storage
> methods, or should I just call the API again, on other pages?

No,you don't need to call the API on other pages.

If you save the data after you call the API, then you can access the values from all the pages of your app.

Both [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android) and [Secure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android) could achieve the same result.

And uninstalling the application causes all preferences to be removed, except when the app runs on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later, while using the [Auto Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) feature.

And `SecureStorage` uses the [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android) API and follows the same data persistence outlined in the [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android#persistence) documentation.

However, data of `SecureStorage` is encrypted with the Android `EncryptedSharedPreferences` class, from the Android Security library, which wraps the `SharedPreferences` class and automatically encrypts keys and values.

So when it comes to security, `SecureStorage` is safer than `Preferences`.

For more information, you can check document [Platform differences of SecureStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android#platform-differences) and [Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android#limitations).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll use your recommendations.